# make specific slides advance back to first slide in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I need some help in setting up the way my presentation runs. Here is what I am hoping to achieve;

I am building a game in the style of jeopardy. I am using slide one as the category grid with hyperlinks to the various question slides. The question stays on screen for 30 seconds at which time the time is up sound plays and the slide auto advances to the next slide showing the answer.

Right now I have to use an image button with a hyperlink to get back to slide 1 for the next player. What I am trying to do is set up an auto advance like from question to answer slide but I want every answer slide to return to slide 1 after 5 secs or so.

I have been searching for a way to do this and have had no luck. There have been many similar questions, but none of the answer will work for my situation.

I have made an illustration of the flow I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any help any of you can offer.

[image: Slide show flow illustration]

Answer (score 1):

In PowerPoint 2016 for Office 365 Subscriber version, there is a new feature **Zoom for PowerPoint** introduced. I think it is helpful for your requirement. I have created a sample file for your reference, click [Here](https://1drv.ms/p/s!AtB-wbnUTwvRo2cXY7ETXAsfceoo) to download it and check if it is what you want.

If it helps, try the following steps:

1. Create **Sections** for Questions (Question 1, Question 2 etc.): Right-click between the two slides where you want to add a section, and then click **Add Section** [image]
2. In first primary slide, click **Insert**, in the **Links** group, click **Zoom** > **Summary Zoom**. Select the question slides, click **Insert**. [image]
3. The slide will be displayed in primary slide, you can right-click the linked slide, select **Change Image** to change displayed picture for them.
4. Set the auto **timing** for question and answer slides: Go to **Transitions** tab, in the **Timing** group, set **Advance Slide**.

For Questions side, set **After 30 seconds**: 
[image]

For Answers slide, set **After 5 seconds**: 
[image]

5. Go to Slide Show, Start Slide Show From Beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the great instructions. I suppose I will have to go through the above process for each Q&A pair. That's 25 pairs of slides.